# Set table's highlighted column text color

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors, highlight

I am implementing a solution to cross-highlight both table rows and columns based on CssTricks `::before` & `::after` + negative `z-index` hack.

The goal is to do it with CSS only, if possible.

I want to set all highlighted cells text to Red color.

For rows it's easy, we just set a rule like `tbody tr:hover td { color: red; }`

But for columns I can't figure out a way to do it...
Is there a way to achieve the same with columns?

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  background-color: silver;
  color: white;
}

td, th {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
}

body:not(.nohover) tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffa;
}

/* font settings for highlighted Row */
tbody tr:hover td {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* font settings for highlighted Column??????? */
/* (how to do it?) */

td:hover::after,
thead th:not(:empty):hover::after,
td:focus::after,
thead th:not(:empty):focus::after { 
  content: '';  
  height: 10000px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;  
  top: -5000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

td:hover::after,
th:hover::after {
  background-color: #ffa;
}

td:focus::after,
th:focus::after {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* Focus stuff for mobile */
td:focus::before,
tbody th:focus::before {
  background-color: lightblue;
  content: '';  
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -5000px;
  position: absolute;  
  width: 10000px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th class="col">50kg</th>
        <th class="col">55kg</th>
        <th class="col">60kg</th>
        <th class="col">65kg</th>
        <th class="col">70kg</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="row">160cm</th>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>27</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="row">165cm</th>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="row">170cm</th>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="row">175cm</th>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>24</td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
</main>
```

See the Pen 
  [Row and Column Highlighting with CSS Only](https://codepen.io/antonio-rodrigues/pen/pBxmpJ/) by antonio-rodrigues ([@antonio-rodrigues](https://codepen.io/antonio-rodrigues))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Expected results:
Set `color: red` for all cells of highlighted Column, keep all other table cells with default black color.

How to achieve that wit CSS only?

Comment: You'll probbaly need `col` / `colgroup` to do that. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate `col / colgroup`. But I've noticed that it will complicate the code tremendously, our tables have several formats, scrollable panels and so on.

Comment: Yeah...there's a reason this is usually done with JS.